# opengl: blending has inconsistent results across platforms

Tags: c++, .net, opengl, graphics, transparency

I'm rendering a circle texture onto triangles in opengl. This works fine.

I enable GL_BLEND, set the the color I want, and then I use glBlendFunc with GL_ONE and GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glColor4(0x0,0xCC,0x0,0xFF);
```

On my main platform (Linux) I get the results I want, where rendering one circle has no square background, and rendering circles next to eachother looks as expected.

However if I change platforms, in this case to windows 10, and I suspect this might not just be a windows-linux issue, but also hardware reliant? I get these results
[image: green circles]

Instead, the circle texture is rendered with what seems to be a semi-transparent white background. So rendering circles on top of eachother yields weird results.

If I use GL_SRC_ALPHA as my first blendfunc param, I remove the issue, but in an issue once again inconsistent between platforms, the texture has grey around the edges.

Comment: Make sure youre testing on the same conditions so: what is the alpha in your texture (it might be image loader issue and not GL itself)? What gfx/driver on both platforms?. What is your pixelformat in both platforms? (bits per `r,g,b,a`)

Comment: @Spektre Specifically, my image is [this](http://i.imgur.com/Fvzd68b.png) with 0 alpha outside of any pixel without 255 alpha. It is loaded using `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNEDBYTE, scan0);` and loads fine and `glGenerateMipMap` is also used after loading. I'm using the [radeon open source driver](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/xorg/radeon/) on linux, and the typical up to date driver on windows for a Radeon R9 280x, by no means an outdated card. Lastly, my pixelformat is 32 bits/pixel (8888).

Comment: `glTexImage2D` loads image from CPU memory to GL memory as texture but how did you load the image from file to CPU memory? (that is image loader and its behavior may be different across platforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inconsistency ended up being what seems like a difference the implementations of the image loader per platform, but interestingly, I did not solve it by changing image loaders.

I actually just changed the way the image was saved. In gimp, the process was: Export image (as png) -> Disable "Save background color" -> Disable "Save color values from transparent pixels", and now the issue no longer appears.